# Querying start and end fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields.

```
tbl_events
====================
id
title
start  -datetime
end    -datetime
status
```

I have the following data in that table.

```
tbl_events
========================
1
Test Title 1
2015-11-14 10:30:00
2015-11-15 15:00:00
active

2
Test Title 2
2015-10-31 00:00:00
2015-11-04 00:00:00
active

3
Test Title 1
2015-11-30 00:00:00
2015-12-1  00:00:00
active
```

I am trying to bring up a calendar and when i pull up the month of november i want to show all these events since they either have a start date or an end date in november. I have the following query which i can get to work with only one field but not sure how to do it when i have a start and end field.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE(start BETWEEN '2015-11-01 00:00:00 AND 2015-11-31 23:59:59)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event overlaps in November if it ends one or after the 1st and starts one or before December begins:

Here is one way to express this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_events
WHERE end >= '2015-11-01' and start < '2015-12-01';
```